# Handle multiple API in a single app with similar model type

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two APIs, let's say :

- `aaa.com/api/v1/events`
- `bbb.com/api/events`

Both implement JSONAPI adapter, and then return a payload with `type="events"`.

As a result, I have to scope those models into subfolders:

- `models/aaa/event.js`
- `models/bbb/event.js`

Which result in querying the models this way:

```
this.get('store').findAll('aaa/event');
```

Then, I have implemented an adapter:

```
// adapters/aaa/event.js

import config from '../../config/environment';
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from "ember";

const { String } = Ember;

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  host: 'aaa.com',
  namespace: 'api/v1',

  pathForType: function(type) {
    return String
      .underscore(type) // `aaa/some-model` -> `aaa/some_model`
      .pluralize() // `aaa/some_model` -> `aaa/some_models`
      .replace("aaa/", ""); // `aaa/some_model` -> `some_model`
  },
});
```

So far so good, Ember correctly calls `aaa.com/api/v1/events`, the returned payload is typed `events` but Ember fails to translate it to `aaa/events`.

How can I proceed ?

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 What doy ou man by _feeling_ ? Did you mean _fetching  ? Is that so, I do `this.get('store').findAll('aaa/event');` (I'lll update the post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you got the model specific  serializer for  `aaa/event` and `bbb/event`. you can overridre `modelNameFromPayloadType` method to translate `events` to your required model name `aaa/events`.

For aaa/event serializer,

```
modelNameFromPayloadType(payloadType) {
  return 'aaa/event';
}
```

Refer:
https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer/methods/modelNameFromPayloadType?anchor=modelNameFromPayloadType

Comment: It didn't worked with `modelNameFromPayloadType` but worked with `modelNameFromPayloadKey`. Thanks !

Comment: Glad it worked. Actually I initially wrote `modelNameFromPayloadKey` after seeing  //TODO deprecation [in code](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.14.4/addon/serializers/json.js#L716) I just modified. any how dont know the reason why is not worked. May be ember-data version might come into play. No problem when they officially deprecate we can change it to `modelNameFromPayloadType`.

Comment: I found why ! We had to enable `"ds-payload-type-hooks": true` in the FEATURES section in the `config.js` it allows usage of `modelNameFromPayloadType` and `payloadTypeFromModelName`

Comment: Yay super :) :)